# Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity PDF to CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need to draw from a Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution to initialise a molecular dynamics simulation. I have the PDF but I'm having difficulty finding the correct CDF so that I can make random draws from it.

The PDF I am using using is:

$$f(v)=\sqrt  \frac{m}{2\pi kT} \times exp \left( \frac{-mv^2}{2kT}\right) $$

I am told that to find the CDF from the PDF we perform:

$$CDF(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x PDF(x) dx $$

After integrating  $ f(v) $ I get:

$$ CDF(v)= \sqrt \frac{m}{2\pi kT} \times \left( \frac{\sqrt\pi\times erf \left( \frac{mv}{2\pi kT} \right) }{2\times \left( \frac{m}{2kT} \right)} \right) $$

$$CDF(v)=  _{-\infty} ^{x} \left[ {\sqrt \frac{m}{2\pi kT} \times \left( \frac{\sqrt\pi\times erf \left( \frac{mv}{2\pi kT} \right) }{2\times \left( \frac{m}{2kT} \right)} \right)} \right] $$

1)After I reach this point I am unable to proceed as I do not know how to evaluate something between $x$ and ${-\infty}$.

2)I am also concerned that I have not done the integration correctly.

3)I want to implement the CDF in C++ in the end so I can draw from it. Does anyone know if there will be a problem with doing this because of the erf, or will I be alright with [this GSL implimentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Error-Function.html) ?

I am not a mathematician so please be gentle with your explanations :)

Thanks for your time

EDIT:

@bryansis2010 says that I can evaluate in the range $x$ to $0$ instead of $-\infty$.

Would this then make the CDF:

$$ CDF(v)= \sqrt \frac{m}{2\pi kT} \times \left( \frac{\sqrt\pi\times erf \left( \frac{mv}{2\pi kT} \right) }{2\times \left( \frac{m}{2kT} \right)} \right) $$

as $erf(0)=0$

Comment: How about you change the lower limit to absolute zero, ie 0 kelvin? That is a lower limit because temperatures in the universe do not fall below 0 Kelvin...

Comment: Thanks, but given the definition of the CDF, would that still be OK?

Comment: i would say it's okay since, by definition, the CDF is cumulative probability that is smaller than a value of $x$.

Comment: cheers @bryansis2010, so then my final CDF is correct? (i.e. is the integration is correct?). Also do you have any thoughts on the GSL erf implementation?

Comment: i'm no physics person, you might want to bring this question to http://physics.stackexchange.com/ to ask

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54207/2451

Comment: @RRs_Ghost: is the MB distribution more like $v^2 e^{- a v^2}$?  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Distribution_for_the_speed

Comment: @rlgordonma it is for speed, but I want velocity.

Comment: @bryansis2010: try not to send pure math questions over to us :) If there isn't a physics concept involved, we'd be happier if math.se kept it.

Comment: @bryansis2010 let me echo what Manishearth said. This question is off topic for us at Physics. Just a tip for the future: if you think a question is off topic for this site, you can suggest that it be migrated (if the migration is erroneous, that's easy to fix), but it's better if you don't suggest to the OP that he/she cross post the question to another site.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky, I got it. As in, I was trying to get some context in the lower limit of the integral. Hence, I suggested Physics stackexchange. In my world (at least), I saw it as a question that I would probably ask at Physics Stackexchange too. I, too, am a regular user for about a month and a half. Perhaps I'm still confused.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF you gave is for a Gaussian distribution.  Your programming language might have a subroutine for generating Gaussian-distributed random variates; if not, inverting the CDF is not the easiest approach.  The [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) is a good place to start.  You give it two uniform random numbers, and it gives you two Gaussian random numbers.

Comment: Of course! I forgot that, thanks @iannucci. According to wiki each component of the velocity vector has a normal distribution with mean 0 and st-dev sqrt(kT/m). Does this mean I can simply sample from a Gaussian CDF with those parameters and achieve the same thing? i.e. 1/2 *(1+ erf[(x-mu)/sqrt(2*sigma^2)])